# Cannot resolve maven dependencies using netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm something of a Maven newbie and I'm unable to download some dependencies that I think should be available. Could someone clue me in on what they think is wrong and how to fix it? I'm getting the following error message:

```
 Failed to execute goal on project gallery: Could not resolve dependencies for project
 com.prospinghibernate.gallery:gallery:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
 dependencies for [log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.0
(compile), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.0 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.0 (compile), 
org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2 (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), 
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1 (compile), javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3 (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (test), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), 
jstl:jstl:jar:1.2 (compile), com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.131 (compile), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.6.2 (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.0-Final (compile), 
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.0-Final (compile),
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final (compile),
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.2.GA (compile), javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA (compile), cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2 (compile),
javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1 (compile), org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile), commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4 (compile), 
 commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3 (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:3.2.1.Final (compile), net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.2.2 (compile),
 org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test),
 org.jmock:jmock-junit4:jar:2.5.1 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2: Could not transfer artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.9.M2 from/to JBoss Repo (http://repository.jboss.com
 /maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt
 /1.6.9.M2/aspectjrt-1.6.9.M2.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

Does the "ReasonPhrase:Forbidden" at the end of the message mean I lack authorization for some of the libraries? What are alternatives?

Here is the pom:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.prospinghibernate.gallery</groupId>
<artifactId>gallery</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gallery</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.5.0-Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss Repo</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
        <name>JBoss Repo</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ibiblio mirror</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- General dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <!-- Exclusions only required for version 1.2.15 of log4j -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- file upload dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- image processing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring OXM-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.131</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ehcache dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate Search-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dozer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.22</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the aspectjrt.1.6.9.M2 was not available. I changed it to 1.6.11 and everything worked fine.